# How to check whether I'm getting data from cache or firestore (JavaScript SDK)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I enabled the firestore cache by calling the `enableIndexedDbPersistence` method in my react app. here is my code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"
import { enableIndexedDbPersistence, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
  // config code
}

initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = getFirestore()
enableIndexedDbPersistence(db) // enable cache

const auth = getAuth()

export { auth, db }
```

I would like to know how I can verify that I'm getting data from the cache, not from the server in the below code?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

import { collection, limit, onSnapshot, orderBy, query, where } from "firebase/firestore"

import { db } from "../firebase/config"

export const useCollection = (c) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    let ref = collection(db, c)

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
      const results = []

      console.log(snapshot.metadata.fromCache ? "local data" : "server data")

      snapshot.docs.forEach(
        (doc) => {
          results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
          setError("could not fetch the data")
        }
      )

      setDocuments(results)
      setIsLoading(false)
      setError(null)
    })

    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [])

  return { documents, error, isLoading }
}
```

Is there anything apart from calling the `enableIndexedDbPersistence` method I need to do to configure the cache properly?

Will this method cache the subcollection documents as well?

Comment: [snapshot.metadata.fromCache](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline#listen_to_offline_data)

Comment: Ok, thanks! Will you be able to answer the questions that I added in the last?

Comment: Welcome, go through the doc page I commented. It covers almost everything. Implement what is necessary for your app

Comment: Wanting to know whether the data comes from the local cache is almost always a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish with this check?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I just wanted to see whether I implemented the enableIndexedDbPersistence method correctly or not.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you suggest a different way to implement caching or something else to reduce the number of reads apart from enabling offline persistence? The problem with this approach is users can't open more than two tabs, and offline persistence is supported only by the Chrome, Safari, and Firefox web browsers.

Comment: `fromCache` will be `false` in some scenarios when the SDK isn't sure if the snapshot is up to date with the server, even when the data comes from the cache. --- If the built-in caching from Firestore doesn't do what you want, you'll have to implement your own caching strategy.

Comment: okay, the problem with built-in cache is that when a user goes from one page to another in a SPA, it fetches data from the server everything instead of just fetching the updated changes.

Comment: How did you determine that it retrieves everything from the server?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When my component is mounted, I log the value of `snapshot.metadata.fromCache` inside the `useCollection` hook and it always prints as false. The code for the `useCollection` hook can be viewed in my question.

Comment: `fromCache` being false does **not** necessarily mean that the snapshot was read from the server as a charged read. Instead it merely means that the snapshot is guaranteed to be up to date with the server. So you can't use `fromCache` to determine whether you're issuing charged document reads, which is why I pointed out the XY problem above.

Comment: got your point! I was trying to get an idea of how much charged read it would cause for one user's session.

Comment: @r121, did any of the comments above address your concern? If so, please post it as an answer so that it would be helpful to other community members with similar questions.